# dLib and Names of recognized features

Tags: python, dlib

I'm using dLib to identify certain facial features on my python app. I can draw the dots over the nose, eyes, and chin.

Here is my code

```
for k, d in enumerate(dets):
    shape = predictor(image, d)
    shape = shape_to_np(shape)
    for (x, y) in shape:

        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        #cv2.putText(image,str(one),(x,y), font, .4,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
        one = one + 1
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

I'd like the entire thing to be identifiable however, so that i can output the "nose" text on the image alongside the identifying dots.

In essence, i'd like to be able to assign the word Nose to the set of dots that make up the nose. Easy?

Answer (score 0):

The dots correspond to a precise part of the face. If you are using the classical 68-landmarks `.dat` file, they are as follows:

- nose: points 27 to 35
- right eye: points 42 to 47
- left eye: points 36 to 41
- mouth: points 48 to 67
- left eyebrow: points 17 to 21
- right eyebrow: points 22 to 26
- contour of the face: points 0 to 16 (chin: 6 to 10)

Answer (score 0):

See below image, In this image, all point are marked according to position on face with numbers

[image]

the 68 landmark point on the face is shown the location of

```
Mouth
Right eyebrow 
Left eyebrow
Right eye
Left eye
Nose
Jaw
```

You want Nose text along to Nose point in picture, then you have to select Nose point

```
nose points from 27 to 35
```

you can select any point between nose point as shown in image , these point are just x y location of the nose

for put text on the image after select point use cv2.puttext method